# sqlite: Fastest way to get all rows (consecutive disk access)

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I want to read all rows in a table using system.data.sqlite. As I have a very big Table (>450GB, with > 6 billion rows) I want to be sure that sqlite will use consequtive disk access. As you may know a random access to hard disk is slow. Due to memory restictions I can not load all the data at once. So the optimal way would be if sqlite reads some hundred MB (consecutive), then I work with this data and sqlite reads the next.

How can I be sure that sqlite will do disk access this way and not jumping from one position on hard disk to another?

Things I know (I think these suggestions will show up):

- It could be better to use an other DBMS. But I want/need to solve it wiht this one.
- I know that the disk head will be positioned by the OS on other data while I am workign with thhe data. This doesn't matter. It is just that some hundret MB will be read consecutively.
- I don't want to / can split the database file up into smaller pieces

I found this post, but it is not addressing my problem correctly:
[Which is the fastest way to retrieve all items in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947165/which-is-the-fastest-way-to-retrive-all-items-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what clustered index are for. sqlite doesn't support them though.

The following is copied from: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuningWindows

> **Four: Clustered Indexes**
>
> SQLite doesn't support clustered indexes (simply, indexes that force
>   the data in the database to be physically laid down in the SAME order
>   as the index needs it to be in.)
>
> This means that if your index is sequential INTEGER, the records are
>   physically laid out in the database in that INTEGERs order, 1 then 2
>   then 3.
>
> You can't make a Clustered index, but you CAN sort your data in order
>   so that any historical data is ordered nicely. Of course, as the
>   database matures, you lose that, but it helps
>
> Someone else posted this, and it is a nice example to use, so I will.
>   If you have a table WIBBLE whose field KEY you want to access a lot,
>   it would be nice if everything was in order. Using the command line
>   tool, you can create a fake cluster by doing the following:
>
> ```
> create table wibble2 as select * from wibble;
> delete from wibble;
> insert into wibble select * from wibble2 order by key;
> drop table wibble2;
> ```

Bottom line is you can re-order your records manually, but I imagine this would be practical for you only if you don't intend to write to the table to often.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, table rows are stored sorted by the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), so the most efficient way to read the rows in this order is to sort by this column (or the alias you declared with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY):

```
SELECT * FROM wibble ORDER BY rowid
```

For a [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table, you sort by the primary key column(s):

```
SELECT * FROM wibble ORDER BY MyPrimary, KeyColumns
```

Answer (score 1):

From @CL. answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293799/does-sqlite-support-indexes):

> In SQLite, indexes created with CREATE INDEX are non-clustered
>   indexes.
>
> Since version 3.8.2, SQLite supports WITHOUT ROWID tables, which are
>   clustered indexes.