# Does SQLite3 supports indexing? How can I speed up a query?

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am executing this query:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"
        SELECT DISTINCT P1.ID_RUTA_PARADAS
        FROM FastParadas AS P1
        WHERE P1.ID_ESTACION_INIT <= %d AND
            %d <= P1.ID_ESTACION_END
        INTERSECT
        SELECT DISTINCT P2.ID_RUTA_PARADAS
        FROM FastParadas AS P2
        WHERE P2.ID_ESTACION_INIT <= %d AND
            %d <= P2.ID_ESTACION_END",
    (int)estacionOrigen.ID_Estacion,(int)estacionOrigen.ID_Estacion,
    (int)estacionDestino.ID_Estacion,(int)estacionDestino.ID_Estacion];
```

And I want to speed it up. I tried by creating some indexes but there is no improvement. Does SQLite3 supports indexes?

The database has 3900+ rows, and this query has to be repeated 1800+ times in less than a second.

Comment: "Good luck with that." Put differently, give up now. Let's consider the *bare minimum* time this could take: N = 4K rows. 1.8K times per second * (N <check P1> + N <distinct P1> + N <check P2> + N <distinct P2> + N <intersect the two> = 1.8K * 20K = 36 million "ops" / second. God forbid you ever have to hit the disk. Or parse the query. Or do *anything*. The only hope you have to evaluate something like this 1,800 times per second is to load the entire table into memory and do this with C code instead of SQL. And even then...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so that means implicitly that there is no built-in b-tree (for indexes), executing queries in sublinear log(n) time for sqlite3?

Comment: The issue here is not the algorithmic complexity of SQLite's implementation, it's the 1,800 queries per sec requirement. Let me put it to you this way: if each query causes an I/O operation, and you assume that a disk access costs at least 0.5ms (and then the latency of waiting to come back to the top of the run queue after getting switched out after doing an I/O op), you're already *totally* dead in the water. If you're planning on having it all in memory, then why use SQLite at all? Just use an array of structs and "query" by writing C code to do the work. SQLite is not the right tool here.

Comment: Here, let me be even more blunt: Doing anything that even *might* cause I/O at 1.8KHz in user-space seems pretty hopeless. By my estimation, even if only 5% of operations caused I/O, you'd already have failed (IIRC the OS X time slice is 10ms.)

Comment: loading the table in RAM and working with plain C, has been a good option. Then By exploiting certain constraints on the data the time spent has diminished considerably. Iam close to the 1.8K/s

Answer (score 2):

> The database has 3900+ rows, and this query has to be repeated 1800+
>   times in less than a second.

No.  Not going to happen outside of a machine with fantastically HUGE memory bandwidth using a highly optimized algorithm that scans the data in memory.

In any situation like this, it is critical that you design that data model such that this kind of query simply isn't necessary.   3900+ rows is really not that much, but 1800+ queries against that data is a hell of a lot.

Your best bet is to pursue a schema that eliminates the need for the 1800+ queries/second or, worst case, design the app such that the 1800+ queries/second is done behind a progress bar or something.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the points from @bbum and @ipmcc regarding physical limtations, you won't have much luck with indexes in theory, too. What you are looking for is the `ID_RUTA_PARADAS` entry of all tuples that satisfy `ID_ESTACION_INIT` smaller than some value and `ID_ESTACION_END` bigger than some value (Just to put that into natural language).

*What could an index help with that?*

(1) Say you have an index on `ID_ESTACION_INIT` that supports range queries. You could get all ids for the rows satisfying `ID_ESTACION_INIT <= %d` relatively fast. But then you have to get all those rows in order to find out if they also satisfy `%d <= P1.ID_ESTACION_END`.

(2) Say you have an index on `ID_ESTACION_INIT` and one on `ID_ESTACION_END` both supporting range queries. Then these both could get all rows satisfying the predicates, and the rowids that are returned by both indexes could be used for fetching the `ID_RUTA_PARADA`.

The problem with both of these approaches is, that if you want to work with them, you would have to do random access to disk which makes only sense for small result sets (i.e. if there are few rows that satisfy those predicates).
For bigger cardinalities (I think I heard of >= 5%, but that might also have been just an example) your database system would go for a tablescan in order to find all tuples which means, your index does not help.

Here a SQLFiddle to play around with indexes and maybe also other DBMSs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d1a86/2

(In fact, a clustered index could help for reading less not-qualifying tuples, but SQLite does not support them: [sqlite: Fastest way to get all rows (consecutive disk access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196295/sqlite-fastest-way-to-get-all-rows-consecutive-disk-access) )

Answer (score 0):

In this query, the `INTERSECT` already takes care of removing duplicates, so you don't need the `DISTINCT`. The following query might be even faster:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ID_RUTA_PARADAS
FROM FastParadas
WHERE %d BETWEEN ID_ESTACION_INIT AND ID_ESTACION_END
  AND %d BETWEEN ID_ESTACION_INIT AND ID_ESTACION_END
```

However, a range query like this cannot be easily optimized with normal indexes.
You should change your database to use a one-dimensional [R-tree index](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html), in which case 1800 queries/s might be possible.

Comment: No, the `%d`s are replaced by different Strings for the two `SELECT`s; one time by `estacionOrigen` the other time by `estacionDestino`

Comment: @contradictioned That is why there are still two `%d`s.

Comment: I executed this query instead of the one above. It is a similar, but essentially a different query, and gives other answers that are not correct under extensive tests.