# Does sqlite support indexes?

Tags: sqlite, non-clustered-index

can anyone tell me if Sqlite supports clustered and nonclustered indexes? and if it does how do i make a column which is non primary key a nonclustered index?
I am very new to database concepts hence very confused..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147957/1864610

Comment: @HoboSapiens That information is outdated.

Answer (score 14):

In SQLite, indexes created with [CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) are non-clustered indexes.

Since version [3.8.2](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_2.html), SQLite supports [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) tables, which are clustered indexes.